# React-admin separated filters on two lists sharing the same resource

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, react-router, react-admin

I'm looking for a solution to a simple problem.
For consistency React-Admin framework provides a "cache" in redux to persist filters on each routes for a specific resource.

**Case:**
I have a page  of Resources "Users".
I have another page  for another entity let say "Group".
To add a User to this Group I have a button that open a  (Dialog) that display the entire list of users and want to have free access to filters on this  element.

**The issue:**
When I update a filter on the Users page  the filter is stored in Redux.
When I open the modal in the other page le Users List is displayed with the stored filter.

**My goal:**
Separate those two sets of filters
OR
Do not store filters states in Redux
OR
Reset filters on opening the modal and on closing the modal.

I found this topic : [How to not change the url on list filtering with react-admin?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59883643/how-to-not-change-the-url-on-list-filtering-with-react-admin)
But I do not understand what component have to be override. My other issue is that I have a second Modal with another  in it let say "FanClub". When I change Filters in one of the two Modal Lists it updates the `?filter=...` parameter in URL causing the second modal to open with filters that cannot be applied to this "FanClub" entity.

Does someone faced this issue before ?

Answer (score 2):

On modal Resource, use a prefixed resource name, e.g., modal:users, then use a proxy dataProvider that trim the prefix.

```html
<Resource name="modal:users" />
```

v2

```js
const trimmerDataProvider => dataProvider => (type, resource, params) => {
    return dataProvider(type, resource.replace('modal:', ''), params)
}
```

v3

```js
const trimmerDataProvider = dataProvider => ({
    ...dataProvider,
    getList: (resource, params) => dataProvider(resource.replace('modal:', ''), params)
})
```

That way user list and modal filter would be stored on diferent keys.

Please note that you must declare the Resource as Admin child, allowing ra to initialize redux stores